# Is NotificationCompat.Builder not compatible for all Android mobiles?

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, android-support-library

Following is my code. I want to show process while downloading song. This code is working in Samsung Tab and Grand but it's not working in Samsung Ace Plus. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
private void Notification() {
    Intent in = new Intent(this, DownloadSong.class);

    final NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Picture Download")
            .setContentText("Download in progress")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    // Start a lengthy operation in a background thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int incr;
            // Do the "lengthy" operation 20 times
            for (progress = 0; progress <= 100; progress += 5) {
                // Sets the progress indicator to a max value, the
                // current completion percentage, and "determinate"
                // state
                mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress, false);
                // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
                mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
                // Sleeps the thread, simulating an operation
                // that takes time
                try {
                    // Sleep for 5 seconds
                    Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "sleep failure");
                }
            }
            // When the loop is finished, updates the notification
            mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
            // Removes the progress bar
                    .setProgress(0, 0, false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(1001, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
    // Starts the thread by calling the run() method in its Runnable
    ).start();
}
```

Following is my dowloading code using service. I want to associate updation of progressdialog  with downloading in notification area.Am I doing correct code?

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
    String urlPath;
    int next = -1;
    private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;

    public DownloadService() {
        super("DownloadService");
    }

    // Will be called asynchronously be Android
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        urlPath = intent.getStringExtra("urlpath");
        String fileName = data.getLastPathSegment();
        final File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                fileName);
        if (output.exists()) {
            output.delete();
        }

        InputStream stream = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());

            while ((next = reader.read()) != -1) {
                fos.write(next);

            }
            // Sucessful finished
            result = Activity.RESULT_OK;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Messenger messenger = (Messenger) extras.get("MESSENGER");
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.arg1 = result;
            msg.obj = output.getAbsolutePath();



            try {
                messenger.send(msg);

            } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
                Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean in this case?

Comment: yes it is compatible to all the device. show the error trace for that devices.

Comment: This code is not able to generate notification in samsung ace plus.

Comment: @chrish how to get error trace of particular device?

Comment: I am using service for downloading the file.

Comment: run your app on that device and look at logcat, there it should be.

Comment: Just comment the `mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());` line in your for loop and then try to run.

Comment: What is the version of the support library? I was using support library v4 revision less then 11 and there was problem on Android 3.0. Once i updated it to revision 11 it start works correctly.

Comment: I added downloading code also.Please check if you find any bug.

Comment: can i use this code for sending update of downloading msg.arg2 = next;

Comment: @Grishu but after its not showing progressbar on notification area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with `NotificationCompat.Builder`. Its with the `IntentService`. I should have used `byte array and DataInputStream` instead of `InputStream` as following:

```
URL url = new URL(urlPath);
            stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
             dis = new DataInputStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            fileData = new byte[url.openConnection().getContentLength()];
             for (int x = 0; x < fileData.length; x++) { // fill byte array with bytes from the data input stream
                    fileData[x] = dis.readByte();

                }
             dis.close();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
            fos.write(fileData);
```